# How can I fix output showing xa017?

Tags: python, string, unicode, character

I grab some data from the web and they all look good. However,once I tried to handle the data and make some operations on their string. The final output showed that some characters become Unicode code. How can I fix it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.fed.cuhk.edu.hk/cri/faculty/prof-lee-kit-bing-icy/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

ref= soup.select('h5:-soup-contains("Selected Publications") ~ ol:nth-of-type(1) li')[-1]
publication_dict= {}

#journal page and periodal
if ref.text[ref.text.find(ref.em.text)+len(ref.em.text)+2:-1] == "":
    publication_dict['remamin_information'] = None

else:
    if periodical != None:
        publication_dict['remamin_information'] = (periodical+ref.text[ref.text.find(ref.em.text)+len(ref.em.text):-1])
    else:
        publication_dict['remamin_information'] = (ref.text[ref.text.find(ref.em.text)+len(ref.em.text):-1])

publication_dict
```

[image: 1]

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: Adding code instead of screenshots is easier for everyone.

Comment: OK, I tried to post my code out. Thank you for your remainder

Comment: As stated, you should provide *text* not images. But in any case, it isn't clear what you mean by "fix it".

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code or of textual program output when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the text, [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the output as if it were code. As for the question: "unicode code" does not make sense. **All text is Unicode whether you like it or not**. What you see in the output is a *representation of* a string, not the actual text of the string - that's so that Python can show you the structure of the data.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the string contained within that dictionary that appears with `\xa0` in it. That is Python showing you the string, *the way that you might type it into program source code*. It is *just like* how the `\n` represents a new line, and not an actual backslash or lowercase n. The `\xa0` escape sequence represents a non-breaking space.

Comment: New code is added for better discussion.  Thanks @KarlKnechtel advise I will change my heading

Comment: Again, there isn't anything wrong. To understand this, try to look up one of the strings in that dict and `print` it, or write it into a file and view it with a text editor.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank a lot! I try to print it as you mentioned, and it shows properly again. But are there any methods to convert back to "normal" string like 17(2), 69-85 in this case in dictionary?

Comment: I cannot give you a set method, because first you have to decide the rules that should be followed. This is a general topic called *normalization*, and it is related to cleaning up user data in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a `list` or `dict`, Python uses a *debug* representation for display of the elements to help identify unprintable characters.  If you actually `print` the string, you'll see the *display* representation:

```py
>>> d = {'remamin_information':',\xa017(2), 69-85.\r\n '}
>>> d     # display the dict.  Elements use debug representation.
>>> d['remamin_information']  # The REPL uses a debug representation
',\xa017(2), 69-85.\r\n '
>>> print(d['remamin_information'])   # the \xa0 is actually a NO-BREAK SPACE
, 17(2), 69-85.                       # and the \r\n becomes a line break
```

There's nothing to "convert back to normal".  Just make sure to `print()` strings to see their display representation.